# Android actiivity_main.xml "@+id" not working

Tags: java, android, xml, eclipse

Today I just started learning how to build an android app in Eclipse and I have my main java file and main xml file. However the id in the main xml file is not "connecting" to the java file. The Java file is in my java package and the xml file is in my layout folder.

(Sorry that I don't know the "android programmer" terms for words. I don't know what the word is for an id "connecting" to another file.)

activity_main.xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="Total is 0"
    android:textSize="45dp" 
    android:id="@+id/tvDisplay"/>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/bSub"
    android:layout_width="250dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/tvDisplay"
    android:layout_below="@+id/tvDisplay"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="34dp"
    android:text="Subtract one"
    android:textSize="20dp" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/bAdd"
    android:layout_width="250dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/bSub"
    android:layout_below="@+id/bSub"
    android:layout_marginTop="26dp"
    android:text="Add one"
    android:textSize="20dp" />
```

MainActivity.java:

```
package com.example.mihirsandroidapp;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

int counter;
Button add,sub;
TextView display;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    counter = 0;
    add = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bAdd);
    sub = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bSub);
    display = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvDisplay);

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.id.bAdd);
    return true;
}
```

}

Comment: You didn't say what the problem was.

Answer (score 3):

Although its not clear which id you are talking about but I guess its `getMenuInflater().inflate(R.id.bAdd);`. This expects an xml file with menu items. Here you've used the id of a `Button`. Correct way to use it is:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.your_menu_file, menu);
    return true;
}
```

Keep the xml in `res/menu` folder. Read [Menus](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html) page from Android documentation for more. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I can't see where your problem is but here are a few things you could try,

- Check that there are no compilation errors (this will prevent the "R" file from updateing)
- Right Click your project folder in eclipse and select "Refresh"

Answer (score 0):

Shobhit is correct you need to add a folder named "menu" inside your "res" folder, and then create an xml file inside the "menu" folder.

Example:

name_of_your_file.xml

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/item"
        android:title="Item"/>

</menu>
```

From here you can access it by doing so...

```
getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.name_of_your_file, menu);
```

Answer (score 0):

you just check in your Gen folder the R file is created or Not Then you Will Build your Project And clean your Project Way to build project is ctrl+B is shortcut and Run the program...